# bash script: result of nested commands result not assigning to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

Having string of pattern:st2-api-alpha

wanted to trim them like st2-api

Basically wanted to remove the text followed by  2nd occurence on '-' for each string.

Below are my statements:

```
    for (( i=1; i<${#all_containers_list[@]}; i++ )){
        echo "trimmed[$i] - "${all_containers_list[i]}|cut -f1-3 -d'-'
        temp="$(${all_containers_list[i]}| cut -f1-3 -d'-')"
        echo "temp is:$temp"

        all_containers_list[i]=$temp
        echo "all_containers_list[$i] is ${all_containers_list[i]}"
    }
```

when i echo:

> trimmed[1] - st2-ui
>
> /home/****/st2-monitoring/monitors/getAllContainerStatus_v1.1.sh: line
> 139: st2-ui-server-alpha: command not found

temp is:

> all_containers_list[1] is
>
> trimmed[2] - st2-api
>
> /home/****/st2-monitoring/monitors/getAllContainerStatus_v1.1.sh: line
> 139: st2-api-alpha: command not found

temp is:

> all_containers_list[2] is
>
> trimmed[3] - st2-whiteboard
>
> /home/****/st2-monitoring/monitors/getAllContainerStatus_v1.1.sh: line
> 139: st2-whiteboard-alpha: command not found

temp is:

all_containers_list[3] is

> trimmed[4] - st2-aspose
>
> /home/****/st2-monitoring/monitors/getAllContainerStatus_v1.1.sh: line
> 139: st2-aspose-alpha: command not found

temp is:

> all_containers_list[4] is
>
> trimmed[5] - determined_bassi
>
> /home/****/st2-monitoring/monitors/getAllContainerStatus_v1.1.sh: line
> 139: determined_bassi: command not found

temp is:

> all_containers_list[5] is
>
> trimmed[6] - st2-ui
>
> /home/****/st2-monitoring/monitors/getAllContainerStatus_v1.1.sh: line
> 139: st2-ui-****-alpha: command not found

temp is:

all_containers_list[6] is

1. `echo "trimmed[$i] - "${all_containers_list[i]}|cut -f1-3 -d'-'`
   --- This is working fine.
2. But the below assignment is not working
   `temp=$(${all_containers_list[i]}| cut -f1-3 -d'-')`

Request your help to fix the same!
OS is CentOS , bash script

Comment: Below also not working  

temp=`echo ${all_containers_list[i]} | cut -f1-3 -d'-'`

Comment: Try `temp=$(echo ${all_containers_list[i]}| cut -f1-3 -d'-')`

Comment: Hi @seumasmac 

Thankyou for your response!
This time, the error is gone, but the result is not having the trimmed value!

Below is the latest log


trimmed[1] - st2-whiteboard
temp is:st2-whiteboard-alpha
all_containers_list[1] is st2-whiteboard-alpha
trimmed[2] - st2-ui
..
..
trimmed[6] - st2-ui
temp is:st2-ui-****
all_containers_list[6] is st2-ui-****

Comment: Why `cut -f1-3 -d'-'`? Shouldn't it have been `cut -f1-2 -d'-'`?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin  -f1-3  is only giving the required output  , like st2-api,     But now the main pblm is , the result is not getting assigned to the variable

Comment: What *result* is supposed to be assigned?

Comment: if input is  st2-api-alpha,   temp should have st2-api,  echo statement is giving right result   but   the same is not being stored to the variable  "temp"

Comment: Can you please help with the required modification..

Comment: `temp=$(cut -f1-2 -d'-' <<< "${all_containers_list[i]}")`

Comment: Excellent!!  Thank you so much @M.NejatAydin     That worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think calling subprocesses just for removing a part of a string, is a bit of an overkill. Assuming that you have stored your string in a variable, say

```
str=st2-api-alpha
```

you could simply do a

```
if [[ $str =~ [^-]*-[^-]* ]]
then
  str=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
```

If the string does not contain a dash, it is left unchanged. You can trvially generalize this solution to your case of having an array of strings.